# What is the smallest number of cards one must take from a deck?

Tags: probability

[image]

I can assume by elimination that 5 or 6 is the correct answer and I tried using combination and the hyper geometric distribution considering a one face as being the M category and the rest of the cards as being the N. However, I am still not able to get 6. I tried to substitute 6 in the hypergeometric formula and I got 0.74. How should I proceed then?

Comment: I think you want to look at the complement: the probability that all cards are different ranks is less than $.4$

Comment: How do I compute the complement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the complementary probability.  The probability that $k$ cards are of different ranks is $$\frac{\binom{13}{k}4^k}{\binom{52}{k}},$$ because there are $\binom{13}{k}$ ways to choose the ranks, and four cards of each rank. When $k=5,$ we get $0.50708$ and when $k=6,$ we get $0.345247.$

**EDIT**

To answer the OP's question about the factor of $4^k:$  This is just a direct application of the multiplication principle.  Say that $k=2.$  I have $\binom{13}{2}=78$ ways in which I can choose the ranks of the two cards.  Say I choose Aces and Kings.  Then I can choose Ace of Spades, Ace of Hearts, Ace of Diamonds, or Ace of Clubs.  Similarly, there are $4$ Kings I can choose.  So there are $4^2=16$ choices in all; for each of the $4$ Aces, there are $4$ possible Kings.

Comment: Why the multiplication with $4^k$?

Comment: @Vizag Because in each of the $k$ ranks there are four cards I can choose -- one of each suit.

Comment: I did not really get the rule of the 4 times k

Answer (score 0):

Let us take $n$ cards. What needs to happen for them to all be different?

After two cards, the chances are $48/51$. The second card just need to have a different face to the first one and there are 48 cards with a different face.

After three, they are $48/51 \times 44/50$. As above but the third card needs to have a different face to the first two.

After four, the chances are $48/51 \times 44/50 \times 40/49$.

Now we need this to fall below 0.4. Let's see what we have.

After 2

$12/13=0.94$

After 3

$48/51*44/50=0.82$

After 4, we multiply the above by $40/49$ to get $0.68$

After 5 $0.51$

So...after $6$

$0.345$ kerching. If we take $6$ cards, the chances of having two the same is $1-0.345$ which is $0.655$